# Collision detection alghorithm for moving objects

Tags: algorithm, performance, actionscript-3, math, collision-detection

Please anybody give me an idea.
There are several (let's say ~20...) objects on screen that move and rotate about their center an each frame. When one object is rotates, his text hint rotates too. The problem is - if two hints come into collision, one of them must move at some angle so as not to collide with another hint.
Please tell me which algorithm should be applied here?

Here is picture to understand it - [ direct link:  [mlkt.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mlkt.jpg) ]. 
[image]

Comment: Keep a rectangle around each object and check collision with that rectangle and the other objects. (Check for rectangle overlap which requires basic math).

Comment: Thanks! Is this a good way for real time? I need to check 360 positions (one per one degrees) after detect the collision to find new and free of collisions position

Comment: Yeah if your object is moving, add/subtract from the x,y coordinates I the rect